# Stick a tag with z-index & position:absolute to certain button inside hamburgur menu to show it always below the button even while resizing the screen

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm woriking on a project that there is a top navbar. On the navbor there is a feedback button on the right corner.
I've created a div of information abouth that button, with `position:absolute` and `z-index`. So when I hover the button with mouse, the `display` of the information box will become `block`, so we can see the box.

But when I resize the screen, and the feedback button comes on the left-bottom corner of the navbar list (it's a hamburgur navbar), the informaiton box still appears on the top-right corner of the page as before and far from the button.

Is there any way that the information box with z-index appears always below the button?

**Update**

```
  [:div
   [:> bs/Button [:span {:style {:margin-left 10}} "Feedback"]]

   [:p {:style
    {:display (if (= nil @(rf/subscribe [::subs/hover-feedback]))
                "none"
                @(rf/subscribe [::subs/hover-feedback]))
     :position "absolute"
     :top "55px"
     :right "15px"
     :z-index "2"
     :border-radius "5px"
     :border "1px solid black"
     :width "300px"
     :padding "5px"
     :background-color "white"}}
"Feedback information."]]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I think there could be multiple solution to the problem. You seem to be using fixed units to position the information box and the feedback button. Use relative units to address the cases of screen resizes.

Comment: @ITgoldman, I just added that block of code.

Comment: @DanFriedman, can you please explain a little more clear please?

Comment: Cant you just put the two elements in a container with a relative position. Then give the information box position:absolute (you did it already), and then not worry about the resizing of the window? Of course, you will have to give width to the containing part?

Comment: @DanFriedman, thank you. I set position:relative to the div tag which contains the button and the feedback information box. Now when I resize the page, the box will be shown under the button, but still on the right side. Because the feedback button is on the top-right in full screen size. When I resize the page, the button will be on the left-buttem corner, and the feedback information box is on the right-buttom below the button. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I can only imagine and not see the design. It seems that the problem is when you resize the screen. I would opt for using media queries, as it sounds that you have a completely different design for each screen size.